# How to load private python package when loading a MLFlow model?

Tags: python, pandas, mlflow, mlops

I am trying to use a private Python package as a model using the `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel`.

My `conda.yaml` looks like

```
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- python=3.10.4
- pip
- pip:
  - mlflow==2.1.1
  - pandas
  - --extra-index-url <private-pypa-repo-link>
  - <private-package>
name: model_env
```

`python_env.yaml`

```
python: 3.10.4
build_dependencies:
- pip==23.0
- setuptools==58.1.0
- wheel==0.38.4
dependencies:
- -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt`

```
mlflow==2.1.1
pandas
--extra-index-url <private-pypa-repo-link>
<private-package>
```

When running the following

```py
import mlflow
model_uri = '<run_id>'


# Load model as a PyFuncModel.
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_uri)

# Predict on a Pandas DataFrame.
import pandas as pd
t = loaded_model.predict(pd.read_json("test.json"))
print(t)
```

The result is

```
WARNING mlflow.pyfunc: Encountered an unexpected error (InvalidRequirement('Parse error at "\'--extra-\'": Expected W:(0-9A-Za-z)')) while detecting model dependency mismatches. Set logging level to DEBUG to see the full traceback.
```

Adding in the following before loading the mode makes it work

```py
dep = mlflow.pyfunc.get_model_dependencies(model_uri)
print(dep)
 
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "-r", dep])
```

Is there a way automatically install these dependencies rather than doing it explicitly? What are my options to get mlflow to install the private package?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here. Turns out the issue is that I was trying to use the keyring library which needs to be pre-installed and is not supported when doing inference in a virtual environment.
There are ways to get around it though.

1. Add the authentication token to the `extra-index-url` itself. You can find it documented in this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036909/how-to-specify-authentication-for-pip-project-setup-pip-with-extra-index-url-in).
2. MlFlow allows you to log any dependencies with the model itself using the `code_path` argument ([link](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyfunc.html#mlflow.pyfunc.log_model)). Using this method, you can skip adding in your private package as a requirement. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75359190/using-code-path-in-mlflow-pyfunc-models-on-databricks) also touches on the same topic.  The code would look a bit like this.

```py
mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(
  path=dest_path,
  python_model=MyModel(),
  artifacts=_get_artifact_dict(t_dir),
  conda_env=conda_env,
  # Adding the current script file as dependency
  code_path=[os.path.realpath(__file__), #Add any other script]
)
```

Opt for first approach if saving authentication token in the `requirements.txt` is feasible, otherwise use the second approach. The downside of using the `code_path` solution is that with each model, your packages' code is getting replicated.