# Using private python packages with databricks model serving

Tags: databricks, mlflow, aws-databricks

I am attempting to host a Python MLflow model using [Databricks model serving](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/index.html). While the serving endpoint functions correctly without private Python packages, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to include them.

#### Context:

- **Without Private Packages**: The serving endpoint works fine.
- **With Private Packages**: I can only use the `--index.url` set to my private PyPI server as detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418655/how-to-load-private-python-package-when-loading-a-mlflow-model).

I wish to avoid storing my token for the private PyPI in plain text. Since [init scripts are not supported with model serving](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/index.html#limitations), I don't know how to inject the token, as a secret at build time. (Could this be possible?)

#### Attempted Solution:

Following [this tutorial](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/private-libraries-model-serving.html), I built the `whl` files, uploaded them to dbfs, and listed them in `pip_requirements` in `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model`. Unfortunately, the file on dbfs cannot be found at build time, preventing the endpoint creation.

#### Code:

Here's how I'm logging the model:

```py
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
            "hello-world",
            python_model=model,
            registered_model_name="hello-world",
            pip_requirements=[
                "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/private_package-0.1.10-py3-none-any.whl"
            ],
        )
```

I have tried different paths in pip_requirements, and the file's existence on dbfs has been verified through both the Databricks CLI.

in `pip_requirements` I have tried:

- `/dbfs/FileStore...`
- `dbfs/FileStore...`
- `/dbfs:/FileStore...`
- `dbfs:/FileStore...`

Command to view package in databricks notebook (this command works!, I can see the file):

```
dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/private_package-0.1.10-py3-none-any.whl")
```

### Error:

The build logs from the databricks serving endpoint produce the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/private_package-0.1.10-py3-none-any.whl'
CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

My hypothesis is that there might be a permission error, and Databricks model hosting might not have access to dbfs. Being new to Databricks, I am unsure how to debug this. Any guidance or insights on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to fix by the following:

After creating the model, please run the command:

```
import mlflow.models.utils

model_uri = 'models:/<model-name>/<model-version>'
mlflow.models.utils.add_libraries_to_model(model_uri)
```

`<model-name>` is the name of your model, and `<model-version>` is the version of the model. In my case the latter is just an integer.

After running this command, there should be a new version for your model. The version number is the highest existing version number increment by 1. Please use this new model version to create the endpoint. The issue should be solved.

P.S. I used the first file path format when creating the model: `/dbfs/FileStore...`

Please refer to Step 3 of the doc:
https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/model-serving/private-libraries-model-serving.html#step-3-update-mlflow-model-with-python-wheels